# Solid state relay voltage ratings -- how to choose?

Tags: voltage, relay, ac, solid-state-relay

I am trying to control mains power, which around here is 220VAC @50HZ. Should I be using a SSR that's rated for 24-280VAC (Load), or one that is rated for 48-480VAC? The reason I'm asking is because I'm currently using a [24-280VAC SSR](http://www.kyotto.com/eng_KD20.htm) ("KD20C25AX"), but I'm getting significant voltage drop at the output. When I read the voltage between live and neutral after the SSR, I'm getting ~55VAC, while at the mains it's the proper 220VAC.

(It's a new SSR so I am assuming it's working properly)

Comment: Either the 280V or 480V relay should work for you.  What voltage do you have across the control terminals when the relay should be on?  The control voltage must be at least 4 volts steady DC.  If the control voltage is low or fluctuating (or AC) the relay may only turn on on random cycles.  Also, what is your load - I recall having problems driving a highly inductive load with a solid state relay.

Comment: The control is steady 5vdc. My load is resistive (a heater). The heater only turns on at 220vac

Comment: Do you think I might have wired it wrong? I have 3 wire AC and the relay is only connected to live on the AC side

Comment: Turns out one of my wires was not getting a full connection. My setup was totally fine! Going to leave this question here so that if people confused about AC think that a 220VAC mains line needs something as beefy as a 480VAC SSR, they might actually be fine with something less!

Comment: Would you mind measure the internal resistor of relay by an Ohm-meter when it is switched on (without load or 220V connected)?